# How to get all jobs status through spark REST API?

Tags: rest, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.5.1 and I'd like to retrieve all jobs status through REST API.

I am getting correct result using  `/api/v1/applications/{appId}`. But while accessing jobs `/api/v1/applications/{appId}/jobs` getting **"no such app:{appID}"** response.

How should I pass app ID here to retrieve jobs status of application using spark REST API?

Comment: I am also having same issue? Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 16):

Spark provides 4 hidden RESTFUL API

1) Submit the job - curl -X POST http://SPARK_MASTER_IP:6066/v1/submissions/create

2) To kill the job - curl -X POST http://SPARK_MASTER_IP:6066/v1/submissions/kill/driver-id

3) To check status if the job - curl http://SPARK_MASTER_IP:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-id

4) Status of the Spark Cluster - http://SPARK_MASTER_IP:8080/json/

If you want to use another APIs you can try Livy , lucidworks
url - https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/3.0/Spark_ML/Spark-Getting-Started.html

Answer (score 10):

This is supposed to work when accessing a live driver's API endpoints, but since you're using Spark 1.5.x I think you're running into [SPARK-10531](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10531), a bug where the Spark Driver UI incorrectly mixes up application names and application ids. As a result, you have to use the application name in the REST API url, e.g.

```
http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/Spark%20shell/jobs
```

According to the JIRA ticket, this only affects the Spark Driver UI; application IDs should work as expected with the Spark History Server's API endpoints.

This is fixed in Spark 1.6.0, which should be released soon. If you want a workaround which should work on all Spark versions, though, then the following approach should work:

The `api/v1/applications` endpoint misreports job names as job ids, so you should be able to hit that endpoint, extract the `id` field (which is actually an application name), then use that to construct the URL for the current application's job list (note that the `/applications` endpoint will only ever return a single job in the Spark Driver UI, which is why this approach should be safe; due to this property, we don't have to worry about the non-uniqueness of application names). For example, in Spark 1.5.2 the `/applications` endpoint can return a response which contains a record like

```
{
   id: "Spark shell",
   name: "Spark shell",
   attempts: [
   {
       startTime: "2015-09-10T06:38:21.528GMT",
       endTime: "1969-12-31T23:59:59.999GMT",
       sparkUser: "",
       completed: false
   }]
}
```

If you use the contents of this `id` field to construct the `applications/<id>/jobs` URL then your code should be future-proofed against upgrades to Spark 1.6.0, since the `id` field will begin reporting the proper IDs in Spark 1.6.0+.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it do not work with the application name or application id.
I ran http://localhost:8080/api/v1/applications and retrieved running app's name and put it there but it returned nothing.

Comment: I am using Spark 1.5.0

Comment: Ah, I noticed that you're using port 8080. Are you accessing the API endpoints of the _master_ web UI? To my knowledge, this _won't_ necessarily work: according to the [REST API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/monitoring.html#rest-api), "the JSON is available for both running applications, and in the history server". While the Master UI happens to implement / support a couple of the API endpoints, I don't believe that all API endpoints work via the master UI.

Comment: When I use port 8080 i.e. of master web ui I am able to get the applications that are running or have been completed. But when I use 4040 i get no response(it says unable to connect not sure what is down). I also tried getting apps from history server i.e. http://192.168.223.106:18080/api/v1/applications but it is also giving empty response. Thanks & Pardon me for silly questions.

Comment: @amit_yo: is your driver web UI starting on port 4040? Are you using the correct hostname / IP to access it?

Comment: Did you encountered in a problem with job names containing whitespace? I get "no such app" in such case.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have this problem and are running on YARN:

According to [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api),

> when running in YARN cluster mode, [app-id] will actually be [base-app-id]/[attempt-id], where [base-app-id] is the YARN application ID

So if your call to `https://HOST:PORT/api/v1/applications/application_12345678_0123` returns something like

```
{
  "id" : "application_12345678_0123",
  "name" : "some_name",
  "attempts" : [ {
    "attemptId" : "1",
    <...snip...>
  } ]
}
```

you can get eg. jobs by calling

```
https://HOST:PORT/api/v1/applications/application_12345678_0123/1/jobs
```

(note the "1" before "/jobs").

Comment: How to know what `PORT` is?

Comment: @huangbiubiu generally it's 4040

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the REST API to control Spark, you're probably best adding the [Spark Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) to your installation which then gives you a much more comprehensive REST API than the private REST APIs you're currently querying.

Poking around, I've managed to get the job status for a single application by running

> curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/v1/applications/Spark%20shell/jobs/

which returned

```
[ {
  "jobId" : 0,
  "name" : "parquet at <console>:19",
  "submissionTime" : "2015-12-21T10:46:02.682GMT",
  "stageIds" : [ 0 ],
  "status" : "RUNNING",
  "numTasks" : 2,
  "numActiveTasks" : 2,
  "numCompletedTasks" : 0,
  "numSkippedTasks" : 0,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "numActiveStages" : 1,
  "numCompletedStages" : 0,
  "numSkippedStages" : 0,
  "numFailedStages" : 0 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark has some hidden RESTFUL API that you can try.
Note that i have not tried yet, but i will.

For example: to get status of submit application you can do: 
curl http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20151008145126-0000

Note: "driver-20151008145126-0000" is submitsionId.

You can take a deep look in this link with [this post from arturmkrtchyan on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/arturmkrtchyan/5d8559b2911ac951d34a)